# Hardisk driver is not found?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, wine, acer

I'm currently using ubuntu 13.10. I am trying to make my laptop dual boot with win 8, but in the win 8 set up, the driver of my harddisk is not found. I've tried to download the driver from the acer website, because I'm using an acer aspire 4736z, but it didn't work. I open it with wine and these words comes up:

> This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing
>   the software.

Comment: this is it.http://i.imgur.com/WYp01BF.png

Comment: you want to resize ext4 partition and then try create a new ntfs partition for windows.Am i correct?

Comment: you have to create a seperate ntfs partition for windows.So that the windows installer can detect that.

Comment: as you can see in my screenshot. i cannot use ikon 'New' to create new partition. so what next

Answer (score 0):

- You can't able to resize a mounted partition on Gparted.In gparted you can easily unmount any partition other than your installed Ubuntu root partition.To unmount your root partition,you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk or Gparted live disk.
- After booting from any one live cd's.Resize the partition you want.I think it's `/dev/sda1`.After resizing,an unallocated space will be  created just below to your `/dev/sda1` partition.
- From that unallocated space create a new ntfs Primary partition.So that your Windows Os will be installed and booted up.
- After that insert your windows installation disk and choose custom option on startup.
- Install Windows on the created ntfs partition.
- Atlast don't forget to run boot-repair.So that both the OS's will be shown on startup.

Comment: i've tried this method too. but my laptop screen has turned to black while the system still work

Comment: while booting from ubuntu live disk,your screen changed into black?

Comment: that is right bro

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: i will try that. but i have another question, is is true that wine can run more than one executable program?

Comment: you mean  running two windows programs at the same time using wine.Try the first option in the above link(black screen while trying to install Ubuntu).

Comment: after you installed wine,you can install .exe files by double click(like we does on windows).Then you can use the installed programs.

Comment: i mean, can i use wine to run 2 .exe files in one time?

Comment: yes you can.If you had any further questions ask that on this site.